# CASE or COALESCE performance in WHERE clause for MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, null, case

I'm wondering which is the better performance or best practice when dealing with multiple criteria in the WHERE clause and NULL values.

```
WHERE
    u.id = COALESCE(user_id, u.id) AND
    su.custom_id = COALESCE(student_number, su.custom_id)
```

OR

```
WHERE
CASE 
    WHEN user_id IS NOT NULL AND LENGTH(user_id) > 0
    THEN
        u.id = user_id 
    ELSE
        su.custom_id = student_number
    END
```

Comment: What were your results when you tested it? How did the query plans differ?

Comment: I'm a SQL Server guy, so my knowledge of how or what kind of Profiler to setup is limited for MySQL.

Comment: Try putting [EXPLAIN EXTENDED](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html) before the Select statements.  If you're used to looking at SQL Server query plans it won't look that much different

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I would avoid both of those approaches. You should be able to accomplish what you are trying to do with a judicious use of `AND`, `OR`, `IS NULL`, and parentheses.

For example, you can rewrite this:

```
WHERE
    u.id = COALESCE(user_id, u.id) AND
    su.custom_id = COALESCE(student_number, su.custom_id)
```

Like this:

```
WHERE
    (user_id IS NULL OR u.id = user_id) AND
    (su.custom_id = student_number)
```

And you can rewrite this:

```
WHERE
CASE 
    WHEN user_id IS NOT NULL AND LENGTH(user_id) > 0
    THEN
        u.id = user_id 
    ELSE
        su.custom_id = student_number
    END
```

As this:

```
WHERE
(user_id IS NOT NULL AND LENGTH(user_id) > 0 AND u.id = user_id)
OR
(su.custom_id = student_number)
```

Comment: You say you'd avoid both approaches, but I think what people are looking for is "why?" Ease of reading? Performance? Impact on use of indexes? Why?

Comment: `CASE` worked for me, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using [explain](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/explain.html) and seehow your query plan is. Like:

```
explain <your select query here>
```

Comment: Which version of workbench you are using? Cause there seems a bug due to which explain not shows any o/p in workbench; which got fixed in Workbench5.2.38. See here, http://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-news-5-2-38.html

Comment: 5.2.37 is my current version.

Comment: Well, then that's a bug with Mysql Workbench as per the doc. You will need to upgrade to 5.2.38.